# How would you UV map some photos of a person?

Tags: texturing, uv

I have a 3D model of a character and a front and back photos of a person. Something like this but in T pose:

[image]

Don't know why I can't delete it.

Comment: I am assuming this would just be for a picture? No rigging (animation) or any thing of that nature will be needed? :) I ask because if not it opens the door for easier ways, you don't have to worry about baking to and from low resolution models.

Comment: @UVBakesandBeyond Animation will be needed :(

Comment: You'll need more images to make this work, at least when you want to show your character from the side. It's not easy painting on a complex model especially if it's supposed to be deformed and still look good. Here's a good start:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lmbAs9jE1vI